# Comparing upper and lowercase letters

Tags: postgresql

In SQL, does 'A' = 'a'?

I took results that I downloaded using sql, the values in two columns matched but they were not supposed to. When I tried to look for a difference, the only difference were capitalized letters in the middle of the word.

Is there a way to make SQL case insensitive? For example THERE is equal to There which is also equal to there or thERE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LOWER function to convert the strings to lower case before comparing.

like this :

```
SELECT *
  FROM tableName
 WHERE LOWER(columnName)='a'
```

using ILIKE instead of LIKE

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE columnName ILIKE 'a'
```

Comment: FWIW, the linked answer for this suggests NOT using ilike, as it is not a sequential read/not using any indexing when searching.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * from table_name where col ilike 'a'
```

using ilike or lower() or upper()